# Через что в Google создают Splash экраны для своих приложений?

Tags: android

Я знаю про способ избавления от "белого экрана" в Android приложениях. Кто не знает, об этом можно узнать [в этой статье](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/312516/). Так вот, а где и как создать хорошую картинку, поддерживающую всевозможные экраны для сплэш-скрина? Раз мы ограничены лишь `drawable`, то максимум как мы можем написать замену XML - использовать `layer-list`.

Вообщем, это за кадром, вопрос вот в чем: во всех приложениях Google показываются однотипные сплэши: иконка в центре и название приложения (одним и тем же шрифтом и цветом, чуть выше низа экрана. Стало интересно, что же за софт/сайт использует Google? Может кто-либо знает?

Сплэши:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLdST.png

https://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2015/06/2015-06-29-22.10.29.png

**UPD**

Не только в гугловских приложениях :) Это однозначно что-то уже готовое и этим все пользуются. Поделитесь, кто знает

Comment: ты можешь не вставлять в вопросы мутированные фотографии? уменьши их хоть вполовину или две трети

Comment: гугл делают так же как и все остальные. как делать drawable под все экраны - тут у сплешей такое же решение как и у других активити. делаешь папочки под все разрешения. сплешам (активити) можно задавать тему. гугл всем своим активити задают один стиль

Comment: android уже давно поддерживает [векторный режим](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) для графики...

Comment: @mit, это ничего не меняет. проблема с зоопарком разрешений экранов остается

Comment: @Flippy вы же задаетесь вопросом, где взять хорошую картинку, поддерживающую всевозможные экраны для сплэш-скрина. Я вам и предлагаю использовать векторный формат вместо растрового. Вектор маштабируется автоматически под экран. Нарезка при этом - не нужна. Или я неверно понял ваш вопрос... В настоящее время не вижу смысла вообще использовать растр в приложениях, если только не поддерживается какая то древняя версия ОС.

Comment: @mit для сплеша нельзя использовать вектор, иначе некорректно отобразится (векторное изображение появится в конце на доли секунды)

Comment: @DeKaNszn не испытываем проблем с отображением векторной графики на сплэш скринах, все работает корректно. В чем вообще разница между сплэш скрином и обычной активити, кроме темы? Разницы другой нет, поэтому не понимаю, почему вы получаете такой эффект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Создаёте `drawable/launch_screen.xml` (`drawable/ic_app_logo.png` - обязательно растровое изображение, векторное отрисуется только в самом конце загрузки приложения):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2) добавляете новую тему:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

3) проставляете данную тему для активити в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

4) меняете тему на обычную для вашего приложения (не обязательно `AppTheme.NoActionBar`) **до** вызова `super.onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}
```

Про размер иконок:

```
mdpi    @ 144.00dp  = 144.00px
hdpi    @ 144.00dp  = 216.00px
xhdpi   @ 144.00dp  = 288.00px
xxhdpi  @ 144.00dp  = 432.00px
xxxhdpi @ 144.00dp  = 576.00px
```

Comment: гугл рекомендует 144dp - соответственно для каждой плотности надо свою иконку

Comment: Не понял. Как я на иконке отмерю 144dp?)

Comment: Добавил размер иконок в ответ